# How do I stop reading a newline from a string?

Tags: c++, string, methods

I have to find a method which displays the 2nd line from a given text. If the text is less than two lines long then it should display "text not long enough". My initial solution was to use the `getline()` function  twice, but the online evaluator refuses to pass one of the tests..

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    string a;
    getline(cin,a);
    getline(cin,a);
    if(a.length())
        cout << a;
    else
        cout << "text not long enough";
}
```

Can you spot the problem and suggest a solution, please?

Comment: You need to check if getline *worked*, did it actually read a line. Also a line can be empty so testing for a zero length string isn't right either. `string a; if (getline(cin, a) && getline(cin, a)) cout << a; else cout << "text not long enough";`

Comment: sorry, forgot to mention that the statement says each line has at least one character != from space

Comment: @john, your solution works!!! if you post it as an answer I will give it a checkmark. Thanks mate!

Answer (score -1):

What should line `if(a.length())` accomplish? It just checks if the string `a` contains at least one character.

In pseudo-code you wrote:

```
if a has at least one character then
    print a
else
    print "text not long enough"
```

That is because if length is 0 it translates to `false`, every other number is considered `true`.

As [john](https://stackoverflow.com/users/882003/john) wrote:

```
if (getline(cin, a) && getline(cin, a))
    cout << a;
else cout << "text not long enough";
```

Which roughly translates to this:

```
bool isInputTwoLinesLong()
{
    int newlines = 0;
    char c;
    while(cin >> c)
    {
        if (c == '\n') newlines++;

        // input contains at least two lines
        if (newlines == 2) return true;
    }

    // input not long enough
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I don't think this answer addresses the fundmental problem which is what to do if the input is less than two lines.

Comment: my bad, forgot to mention that every line has at least one character != from space. So I thought that since the 2nd line has 0 length, the text must be too short

Comment: @john I edited the answer. Does it look any better?